# How does JVM call paint in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm new for AWT/Swing programming. I try to draw an image 100,000 times. The loop of `drawImage()` method is in `paint()` method. I find the times that java calls `paint()` method is quite unstable. It may call `paint()` method two times in one running time of program, but others may call three times. If I create a button that does `repaint()`, it would only call `paint()` one time each I click this button.

Could someone tell me when the `paint()` method would be called? I know System-triggered Painting and App-triggered Painting. But I think it doesn't belong to any of these cases.

Comment: `I know System-triggered Painting and App-triggered Painting. But I think it doesn't belong to any of these cases.` - what other case would there be?

Comment: On this level, Swing is self-contained, and the JVM doesn't tell it anything. That said, you need to call `repaint` each time you think your panel should be painted.

Comment: Swing is uses a passive paint process, that is, the time paint is called random and based on decisions the RepaintManager makes. If you want to control when paint is called, you will need to use an active painting approach.  Having said, unless the images are changing in some way, I'd render the, to a backing buffer/I age first and simply paint that to the graphics context when ever paint is called.  You might like to have a read through [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for a more detailed look at the paint process

Comment: The repaint manager can coalesce multiple repaint requests when they occur close to each other. It's quite possible that in your application only some repaints are actually done, as others are decided to be unnecessary.

Comment: @camickr In my case, I use draw image 100,000 times in paint() method, but I found it was called 2 times or 3 times for each running time. How does second and third time of paint is called? I checked System-triggered Painting and App-triggered Painting, and found there is no case match for this. BTW, the time of calling paint is not stable

Comment: @KenanLiu 1st rule of Swing, you don't control the paint process.  Swing will decide what and when to paint.  There could be a million reasons why you might get different results between runs depending on where the mouse is and what's doing and other system events.

Comment: **** Nowadays, the Java API is open-source code.  You could try setting a breakpoint on the paint() method that you are interested in and see the stack at that point.  This could help you to understand what it happening, stepping through the Java API source code, though with painging, this could be problematic.  This kind of technique is more useful in understanding other parts of the Java API besides the painting process, but it might be helpful to you to understand how it all works.  There's nothing like reading the source-code for yourself. *******

Answer (score 0):

You can use another thread to call the *repaint()* metho. An easy way to do this is to make your painting class (java.awt.Canvas or as here javax.swing.JPanel) implement Runnable and start that Thread in the constructor. Also add the *run()* method.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawPicktures extends JPanel implements Runnable
{
    public DrawPickture()
    {
        /* Code */
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void Paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.Paint(g); // Will draw all gui components added
        /* Code */
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            repaint();
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000  /* Waits for 1000 milliseconds */);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because the JPanel (or Canvas) will be repainted from another thread it won't block up your main thread  so your program can do other stuff at the same time.